# Why this code doesn't work - Debug Current Istruction Pointer issue

Tags: java, debugging

I have been trying to fix this code. The problem is to find the number equivalent for a string, following the rule that the alphabetic series `ABCDEF` are in Fibonacci series `A=0, B=1, C=1, D=2, E=3, F=5` so on. Ex. ABC=0+1+1=2(the output).

When I run the code, it shows me a Debug Current Instruction Pointer inside a for loop. What is wrong and why?

```
 public class faboalpha {

        public static void main(String[]args){
            String gst="MAN";
            char ser[]={'A','B','C','D','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

            int cor[]=new int[26];
            cor[0]=0;
            cor[1]=1;
            cor[2]=1;
            for(int i=3;i<26;i++)
                cor[i]=cor[i-1]+cor[i-2];

            char gchar[]=new char[gst.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<gst.length();i++)
                gchar[i]=gst.charAt(i);

            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<gst.length();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<=25;j++){
                    if(gchar[i]==ser[j]) // <----------- Debug Current Instructor Pointer, why?
                        sum=sum+cor[j];
                }
            }

            System.out.println(sum);
        }


}
```

Comment: Maybe you have a breakpoint over there?

Comment: lol java and pointers tagged together!

Comment: Fabonacci??? Distant relative?

Comment: By the way, you should consider dropping such poor naming conventions, especially when asking for help here because your code is very hard to read with such strange variables `ser` , `gst`, `gchar`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for `j = 25` the index is out of bounds, because the `ser[]` array is too short, i.e. `ser.length` is most probably smaller than 26 and thus `ser[j]` will cause you errors.

Hint: look for the letter `'E'` which seems to be missing (`'A','B','C','D','F',...`).

Second hint: try to follow the message and use a debugger to debug what's going on there.

Third hint: I'd personally use `for(int i=3;i<cor.length;i++)` instead of `for(int i=3;i<26;i++)` and `for(int j=0;j<ser.length;j++)` instead of `for(int j=0;j<=25;j++)`.
Actually, I'd probably even initialize `cor[]` to `new int[ser.length]` or check if they are both of equal length.